# Select row from mysql query and save it to variable

Tags: mysql, pdo

How can I select a row from mysql query and save it to variable using PDO? Previously I did it like this

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

  $ID = $row['ID'];
```

Now i read from the PHP manual that `PDOStatement::fetch()` is alternative to `mysql_fetch_array`but I can't figure out how to use it. This is what I tried but obviously it doesn't work

```
 <?php
include 'config.php';

$sql = "select * from table1";

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);  
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $dbh->query($sql);  
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $dbh = null;
    echo '{"items":'. json_encode($result) .'}'; 
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
}

$row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
  $ID = $row['ID'];


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `PDO::FETCH_OBJ`, you must use object notation to retrieve elements in the result. Since you had already called a `fetchAll()` method, you cannot call another fetch/fetchAll method later on as the data will no longer be accessible.

In place of `$row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);`, iterate over the `$result` variable that you previously had `fetchAll()` return into:

```
foreach($result as $row)
{
    $ID = $row->ID;
    // Etc...
}
```

Comment: when i try to echo $ID it gives me error `Undefined variable:`

Comment: @user1323294, get rid of the `$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);` line in the `try` block. Reason is because you won't have access to the data after `fetchAll()`.

Comment: but if i take `$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);` it shows "null" as `json_encode($result)`, right? could you provide me a full sample with the code in my post please.